# How to set animation in css?

Tags: html, css

How to put my text moving from beginig to the end of the div constantly. I did something like this http://jsfiddle.net/swh2jqrg/ on my web page, but my message is going out in new line. I want that my text goes in a loop(circle). how to do that? my css looks like this:

```
.message1{
width: 1240px;
height: 94px;
font-size: 70px;
text-align:center;
color: white;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-name: slidein;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-delay: forwards;
animation-direction: normal;
}
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }



 to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
      }

}
```

Why this isn't working in Crome? sorry for the english and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use another method  with `text-indent` and `text-shadow` to have no wholes in between each loops :[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JrIeb)

```
.message{
  width: 1240px;
  background-color:#5292a5;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-shadow:0 0 2px red, 1240px 0 , 1240px 0 2px blue;/* pick here another color for text mirrored */
  animation:slidein infinite 10s linear;
  font-size:60px;
  color:turquoise;
  line-height:94px;
}
.message1 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  text-indent:0;
}
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    text-indent:-100%;
  }
 to {
    text-indent:0%;
      }
}
```

Comment: for the prefix, since browser update quiet fast today, you can just write your CSS as plain/regular and use a javascript to add necessary prefix on the fly. Lea verrou has this prefixfree script , but there's a fe others, pick one up and stop wasting time adding , then updating your prefix in your style sheets :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add vendor prefixes for chrome, `-webkit-`:

```
.content1{
    width: 1280px;
    height: 322px;
}
.message{
    width: 1240px;
    height: 94px;
    background-color:#5292a5;
    margin: 25px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.message1{
    width: 1240px;
    height: 94px;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: forwards;
    animation-direction: normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
  }
}
```

Demo in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swh2jqrg/1/

---

Also, in order for the animation to work in mozilla and opera you'll need to add the `-moz-` and `-o-` prefixes as well.

ie:

```
.content1{
    width: 1280px;
    height: 322px;
}
.message{
    width: 1240px;
    height: 94px;
    background-color:#5292a5;
    margin: 25px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.message1{
    width: 1240px;
    height: 94px;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
    -moz-animation-name: slidein;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-delay: forwards;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;

    -o-animation-duration: 10s;
    -o-animation-name: slidein;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-delay: forwards;
    -o-animation-direction: normal;

    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: forwards;
    animation-direction: normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
    height:94px;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 1240px;
    height:94px;
  }
}
```

Demo in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swh2jqrg/3/

Comment: Man, I thought that might have been it, but I'm surprised how long Chrome has taken to drop those prefixes. Another note to OP: You should look into animating "transform: translate(0px, 0px)" rather than margin-left, as that should give better animation performance on most browsers.

Comment: @Katana314 agreed; its also more semantic, and frees up your site's styles. great point.

Comment: I put everything what agconti said and now it works in crome but it doesnt't work in mozila. How to put that text goes in circle?

Comment: @user3569696 like I said in the after post section, you'll have to duplicate everything that has a `-webkit-` prefix with a `-moz-` and`-o-` prefix.

Comment: Thanks, now it works ;) and what about my second question- how to set that text goes around in the circle in that blue div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add vendor prefix `-webkit-` for **Chrome**/**Opera**/**Safari**. Check **[CanIuse?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)**

**CSS**

```
.message1{
    width: 1240px;
    height: 94px;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: forwards;
    animation-direction: normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
    from {
        margin-left: 0%;
        width: 300%; 
        height:94px;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: 100%;
        width: 1240px;
        height:94px;
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/cu8ypjka/)**